# Flutter Drawer menu with master/details example

Tags: flutter, master-detail, drawer

I'm looking for an example that would show how to implement simple drawer menu and master/details screen. I currently have a solution, but it has a flaw. The issue is that when an item in master list view is clicked, the whole drawer is replaced by details screen.
I would like to have drawer **always visible**.
Is there simple example for this? I haven't found one :/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a drawer that is always visible is just a `Row` item?

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 240.0,
      child: <master>,
    ),
    Expanded(child: <detail>),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Not what I wanted but useful!

Answer (score 0):

I have discover that this is not optimal solution. Best practise shows that opening details always hides drawer menu like in Gmail or other Adndroid apps..